# Asynchronous Programming C#

Tags: c#, email, asynchronous, async-await

I am building a Signup screen. After user submits his details an email is sent to his email Id providing him an activation link. Signup details of user are submitted to the server (ASP.MVC controller action) using jquery Ajax(ASYNC POST REQUEST).

First these details are saved to the database and then an email is send to the user by calling SendEmail method.

I have created this SendEmail method as a Async method. Below is how I have implemented it :

```
public async static Task SendEmail(Dictionary<string, object> parameters, string connectionString)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand sqlComm = conn.CreateCommand();
                sqlComm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlComm.CommandText = "emailSendingProc";

                foreach (var param in parameters)
                {
                    if (param.Value == null)
                    {
                        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + param.Key, DBNull.Value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + param.Key, param.Value);
                    }
                }

                await SendEmail(conn, sqlComm);
            }
        }

private async static Task SendEmail(SqlConnection conn, SqlCommand sqlComm)
        {
            try
            {
                await conn.OpenAsync();
                await sqlComm.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               //Log Exception
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

FYI : The emails are sent from the database using a stored procedure "emailSendingProc". The database sending email is different from the one in which Signup details are saved.

If there is any failure in email sending (connection timeout, db server not responding etc) I dont want user to experience that and thus I swallow the exception but log it.

Is the usage of Async method for this requirement justified?

**Edit :**

As a POC I used normal methods as against async method and checked the response time of the browser request in case db connection fails. I could have uploaded comparison images but do not have the reputation to do so :(

I observed that the response time when using Async methods is very less compared to normal methods. Below is the implementation of normal methods :

```
public static void SendEmail(Dictionary<string, object> parameters, string connectionString)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand sqlComm = conn.CreateCommand();
                sqlComm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlComm.CommandText = "emailSendingProc";

                foreach (var param in parameters)
                {
                    if (param.Value == null)
                    {
                        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + param.Key, DBNull.Value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + param.Key, param.Value);
                    }
                }

                SendEmail(conn, sqlComm);
            }
        }

        private static void SendEmail(SqlConnection conn, SqlCommand sqlComm)
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var mess = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Any thoughts why is it faster when Async methods are used?

Comment: async is not related to the hiding of exceptions but yes this will hide the exceptions

Comment: Actually the reason I am hiding exceptions is that it takes a long time for system to determine that there is a connection failure. During that time i dont want my app to be unresponsive. Thus I declared sendEmail as a async method.

Comment: @Aashish: `async` does not return to the browser. The request will not be completed until after the `await` is done and the response is returned.

Comment: Yeah its seems so. Would you suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a valid scenario for using async. By using the async pattern, you are freeing up worker threads to handle more incoming requests while waiting for a response from your database, therefore increasing possible throughput under load.

Answer (score 0):

This will not return to the browser any faster, using async in this way allows your thread to be re-used and waits will be done on IO complete. So its good.

See this blog, not mine but an awesome name :)

http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

If you don't want the user to wait for the email operation then you should consider queuing them up and having something to process the queue. ( I am assuming that the SQL call might send the email)

Comment: Don't be tempted to use Task.Run without an await to send your email btw :)

Comment: Yeah queuing seems to be the last resort :)

Comment: Will Task.Run return control to browser any sooner?

Comment: I think queuing might be a valid option, you could always use SQL agent to trigger the sends every few mins. That's how systems such as CRM do it. You don't want you code to only work if the email server is up etc.

Comment: If you DONT await then you get a compiler warning and it will just run your code and not WAIT for it. BUT this is a bad pattern. It will spin a thread.. This would be a BAD pattern :)

Comment: Let's say I right like this :

await Task.Run(()=> SendEmail(conn, sqlComm));

Comment: I would, change sproc to insert into table, create new sproc to read table and email, create SQL agent job to run your sproc.. If I had longer I would use a Windows Task and a custom EXE as I don't like to have this type of JOB in SQL.

Comment: Will Task.Run create a new thread such that UI thread task gets completed and control returns to browser comparatively sooner?